# Writing conditional HTML with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Depending on my record, I'd like to change the style of the table row in my current iteration.

The below example doesn't work, but how would I go about doing this correctly?

```
 foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    @{ 
                        if (item.DataState != DataState.Active)
                        {
                            <tr style="background-color: red">
                        }
                        else
                            <tr>
                    }
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                  </tr>
                 }
```

So effectively, I'd like to dynamically render the `<tr>` element differently based on the DataState of my model.

Comment: Since you are already in a code block (foreach) you don't need to add an other code block with @{}. There is an other issue in your code - Razor doesn't support IF and ELSE without brackets. You have to put the else part in brackets. Look at my answer - there's a shorter approach.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a shorter approach:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr @(item.DataState != DataState.Active ? "style=background-color:red" : "")>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The row renders as: `<tr red;&#39;="" style="'color:">`

Comment: I fixed it by removing all whitespace from the css properties and values. Strange. Its now: `<tr @(item.DataState != DataState.Active ? "style=background-color:rgba(255,0,0,.1)" : "")>` Could you please update your answer to note the whitespace? Then I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I've fixed the code. I would suggest you to use css classes instead of changing style like this.

Comment: You're right, but for the sake of the example you provided, others might try it verbatim and find it doesn't work off the bat :)

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple way you can write condition.

**Option 1:**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.DataState != DataState.Active)
    {
        <tr style="background-color: red">
            <td>@item.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {
       <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
       </tr>
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr style="@( item.DataState != DataState.Active ? "background-color: red;" : "" )">
        <td>@item.Name</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Def the most thorough answer. #thumbsup @sender

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what kind of error you faces right now, but i gess your problem is that Razor don't understand all cases of tricky html render.

You can force him to render `html` where you need with `@:` symbol for single string or `<text>` tag like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    if (item.DataState != DataState.Active)
    {
        @: <tr style="background-color: red">
    }
    else
    { 
        <text><tr></text>
    }
    <td>@item.Name</td>
    </tr>
 }
```

Comment: I know that's an old post but it was just exactly what I needed today.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Define the attributes in a variable. The razor parser will omit the attribute if its value is `null`

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  var attributes = item.DataState == DataState.Active ? null : "background-color: red";
  <tr style=@attributes>
    <td>@item.Name</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to get compile errors if you start splitting the `<tr>` tag up in the view and I'd not duplicate large chunks of code. I would do the following:

```
@foreach(var item in Model) {
    string strStyle=String.Empty;
    if(item.DataState!=DataState.Active) { strStyle = "background-color:red;" }
   <text>
   <tr style="@strStyle">
       <td>@item.Name</td>
   </tr>
   </text>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @(item.DataState != DataState.Active  ? "style=" + "background-color:red" : "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model?.District?.Name) ? Html.Raw($"<span class=\"location\">{Model?.District?.Name}</span>") : string.Empty)
```